# Another bad (really bad!) close review audit

Tags: support, review-audits

When [this question came up in the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257362/whats-the-best-option-for-creating-a-gui-for-golang) I was certain it was an audit verifying I would *close* it as
**Off topic: asking to recommend a favorite tool, library, offsite resource, whatever..**

Turns out to have been the opposite - it was a review audit expecting me to **Leave Open** which  I failed.

> #### What's the best option for creating a GUI for golang
>
> I want to know what my best choice is for creating a GUI desktop application with Go.
>
> Is it best to use a browser based ui like webkit?

That's it; that's literally the whole thing, which got 5 upvotes. It seems like a pretty clear case for closure recommending favorite tools & libraries, or even "primarily opinion based" to me. Can this get taken out of the review audits?

Comment: Downvote the question and it'll be out of the review audit.

Comment: Automated processes make mistakes. I agree it should be closed and have added my vote

Comment: That is solved rather quickly...